# problem of unauthorized in IBM watson assistant Nodejs

Tags: node.js, watson-assistant

I tried the API Nodejs v1 and v2 of IBM Watson assistant to creat a new conversion. But it gived me always the same error code 401 Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. i don't know what happened, thanks in advance for your answers.

```
{ Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
    at RequestWrapper.formatError (E:\Documents\Techniques\Desktop\front_back_end\version-watson\node_modules\ibm-watson\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\requestwrapper.js:218:21)
    at E:\Documents\Techniques\Desktop\front_back_end\version-watson\node_modules\ibm-watson\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\requestwrapper.js:206:29
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'Unauthorized',
  code: 401,
  message: 'Access is denied due to invalid credentials.',
  body: '{"code":401,"error":"Unauthorized"}',
  headers:
   { 'x-backside-transport': 'FAIL FAIL',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'x-dp-transit-id': 'gateway01-1474836587',
     'x-global-transaction-id': '7ecac92c5d14b5ae57e8386b',
     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000;',
     'x-dp-watson-tran-id': 'gateway01-1474836587',
     'content-length': '37',
     'x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt': '82',
     'x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency': '110',
     date: 'Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:25:18 GMT',
     connection: 'close' } }
```

the document API of IBM assistant shows me the code like:

```
const AssistantV1 = require('ibm-watson/assistant/v1');
const service = new AssistantV1({
  version: '2019-02-28',
  iam_apikey: '{apikey}',
  url: '{url}'
});

service.message({
  workspace_id: '{workspace_id}',
  input: {'text': 'Hello'}
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

I am not sure that for Version2 the session-id is correct or not. But the API v1 doesn't need the session_id, it gives the same error code too.

I want to comfirm that 'Assistant Settings', 'API details', we can find the information of keys.
And'{apikey}' is 'Service Credentials--->passeword', and '{workspace_id}' is 'Assistant Details ---> Assistant ID '. What i confirm is correct, right?

Comment: do you have IBM Cloud account? because at the first you should have account.

Comment: @mohammadjavadahmadi yes, i have the account of IBM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On V1 all credentials information's can be get through "View API Details" on your Skill.
[image: View API Details]

The apikey are on the item Service Credential/Password (the username will be apikey). The workspace ID are also on this interface.

The assistant is used only with the v2, where the session ID is given to you during the first message of the conversation.

Comment: If you are still having issues, after getting the API details from above. Replace the {iam_apikey} with "username": "apikey", "password": {apikey}

Comment: yes, i got the problem, for V1, i have to go to the skill to find "iam_apikey" not the assistant. Thanks a lot.